# Vertically centre the contents of a DIV in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to align the content of a jQuery grid's block vertically at the middle so that it is aligned with the other element in the same row.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" style="border:1px solid">
<div class="ui-block-a" style="vertical-align:middle" ><span>My Text</span></div>
<div class="ui-block-b" >
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neilghosh/9HNjf/1/

I wanted to show the text "my text" at the centre of the box so that is aligned with the select box at the right side. One work around was to have some top margin for the left div but fixing the the pixels might not be a good idea if browser is re-sized.Please suggest any CSS I should consider.

Comment: Have you thought about using line-height? While I would recommend creating a more elegant solution overall, line-height:95px; will get you just about what you want.

Comment: Yeah , tried that but when the text wraps to the next line, there is a problem like this http://jsfiddle.net/neilghosh/9HNjf/3/

Comment: I would declare a height, use overflow:hidden;, or perhaps even an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

A **dirty** solution using jQuery to dynamically adapt the position of the text container div:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" style="border:1px solid">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="position:relative">
        <div id="tc" style="position:absolute">My Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
            <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
            <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
            <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
            <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
var rowHeight = $(".ui-block-b").height();
$(".ui-block-a").height(rowHeight);
var tcHeight = $("#tc").height();
var top = rowHeight / 2 - tcHeight / 2;
$("#tc").css('top',top);
```

You can test here:
http://jsfiddle.net/giofiddle/9HNjf/4/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, a three box grid with buttons on the ends and text in the middle box.  The text was top aligning.  But I noticed JQM was correctly vertically aligning the buttons in the middle of their grid block.  I looked at the style being applied to them.  It was ui-btn-inner.  So here's what worked for me.

```
<div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui-btn-inner">my text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set them as equal high (see http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/ ) to be able to position them correctly.